# MDX: I need only those highlighted records

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need only those highlighted records.

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[Assessment Patients Detail] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY([DimAssessment].[Assessment Text].&[Employee Wellness HRA],
          [DimAssessment].[Question Text].&[Do you use tobacco products?],
          [DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key],
          Generate(
              [DimAssessment].[Answer Text].[Answer Text].MEMBERS
             ,[DimAssessment].[Answer Text].CURRENTMEMBER
             *TAIL(
                NonEmpty(
                   [DimDate].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key].MEMBERS
                  ,[DimAssessment].[Answer Text].CURRENTMEMBER
                )
              ,[DimAssessment].[Question Text].&[Do you use tobacco products?]
              )
          )
)ON ROWS
FROM
[Care];
```

[image: ]]

Comment: I am surprised that this code executes?

Comment: @whytheq- why you surprised this is your query (You comment last week), but excepted result set is not dispalyed

Comment: you have this as the second argument to Tail: `,[DimAssessment].[Question Text].&[Do you use tobacco products?]` ...the second argument should be an integer ... so I am surprised.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the answer as I've tried to help with this before but the following is a little mysterious:

The second argument of the function `Tail` is usually an integer e.g. 2 or 3 which means you would like the last 2, or last 3, members from the set specified in first arg of `Tail`.

I prefer to use cross-join rather than a tuple for members on rows but I don't think this will give you the rows you require:

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[Assessment Patients Detail] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
     {[DimAssessment].[Assessment Text].&[Employee Wellness HRA]}
    *{[DimAssessment].[Question Text].&[Do you use tobacco products?]}
    *[DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key].members
    *Generate(
         [DimAssessment].[Answer Text].[Answer Text].MEMBERS
        ,[DimAssessment].[Answer Text].CURRENTMEMBER
        *TAIL(
           NonEmpty(
              [DimDate].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key].MEMBERS
             ,[DimAssessment].[Answer Text].CURRENTMEMBER
           )
         ,1 //[DimAssessment].[Question Text].&[Do you use tobacco products?]
      )
     )
ON ROWS
FROM
[Care];
```

We will need to move more of the logic inside the generate.

First try the following to see if it returns two correct columns?

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[Assessment Patients Detail] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
    Generate(
         [DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key].MEMBERS
        ,[DimPatient].[Patient Key].CURRENTMEMBER
        *TAIL(
           NonEmpty(
              [DimDate].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key].MEMBERS
             ,[DimPatient].[Patient Key].CURRENTMEMBER
           )
         ,1 
      )
ON ROWS
FROM
[Care];
```

Comment: @whytheq- showing error message  'Query (4, 6) The Multiply function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used.'

Comment: @whytheq- can you please replay on this, I need latest date and latest answer for each patient.